# how to find root**power=number and print out "cannot find the number" message?

Tags: python

I want to print out root and power,
where `0 < power < 6` and `root^power=number` (entered by the user),
otherwise it should print out `"no such a number"` message

here is my work:

```
number=int(raw_input("enter the number:"))
power=2
root=0

while power<6:
    while root**power < abs(number):
        root=root+1
        if root**power==abs(number):
            if number<0:
                print 'root=',-root
            else:
                print 'root=',root
            print 'power=',power

    power=power+1
    root=0
```

It works well, but
I have no idea where to put `"no such a number"` message. Please help!

Comment: What is power is even that root=-root will not work

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log

Comment: Two options. 1) `return` when you find the root. Then if you reach the bottom of the method (e.g. you did not find the root) you can print "No such number." 2) set a boolean to `True` when you find the root. Then at the bottom of the method check if the boolean is True, if it is not print "No such number."

Comment: You should really be using for loops.

Comment: NOTE: An optimization would be to just do `root = abs(number)**(1.0/power)` rather than iterating over values of `root`. Then of course check that `root` ~= `int(root)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for-else/while-else:

```
number=int(raw_input("enter the number:"))
power=2
root=0

for power in range(6):
    while root**power < abs(number):
        root=root+1
        if root**power == abs(number):
            if number < 0:
                if power % 2 == 1:  # Note a change here, 
                                    # you won't get negative number with even power
                    root = -root
                    print 'root=',root
                    print 'power=',power
                    break
            else:
                print 'root=',root
                print 'power=',power
                break
    if root**power == number:  # Make sure we break "for" too
        break
else:
    print "No such number"
```